# Unterschied zwischen "transzendent" und "transzendental"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, word-choice

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *transzendent* und *transzendental*?

Wie würde man es in diesem Fall eher sagen?

> Chi, das transzendente Licht.
>
> Chi, das transzendentale Licht.

Comment: Vielen Dank für eure Antworten

Comment: Ich kenne zwei Leute, die auf »Chi« hören. Plötzlich sehe ich sie vor meinem inneren Auge bunt leuchten …

Comment: @Jan: Auf dieses Chi kann man auch hören? Ich dachte, das ist so eine Art Fluss, weil ich schon mehrfach gehört habe, dass es ganz wichtig sein soll, dass dieses Chi fließen kann. Ich habe aber noch nicht rausgefunden für wen das wichtig ist, und warum.

Comment: @Jan Oh, das tut mir leid. Die Frage entstand aus einem Perry Rhodan Hörspiel (genauer: Atlan Traversan Zyklus)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Die Chinesische Sprache ist sehr reich an homophonen oder bis auf den Ton homophonen Begriffen. 

氣 (pinyin Umschrift: Qi)  ist ein Chinesischer Begriff mit unglaublich vielen Bedeutungen. Von Gas und Luft (etwa in einem Ball) bis hin zu einer Art Lebensenergie in der Chinesischen Medizin. Es kann auch noch ein Verb sein. 

Diese "Energie" und ihre Zirkulation ist nach untenstehender Seite (Chinesisch) für die Chinesische Medizin das wichtigste überhaupt für den Körper, die Funktion seiner Organe... 
http://www.shen-nong.com/chi/principles/qi.html

Comment: @Jan Es gibt sehr viele Nachnamen (häufigere wären 齊、戚,祁...)   die bis auf den Ton gleich (wie 氣） ausgesprochen werden. Aufgrund der Art wie Vornamen sehr frei aus den Zeichen ausgewählt oder kombiniert werden sind auch sehr viele Vornamen denkbar die "Qi" lauten, sowohl männliche als auch weibliche (琪,骐,棋) :)

Comment: @Ludi warum @mich? ;)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Naja … Das sind Spitznamen, die sich Deutsche gewählt haben, weil sie sich in Manga- und Animefreundeskreisen bewegen ;)

Comment: @ Du erwähntest doch den Namen, oder?

Answer (score 9):

**Mathematik**
In der Mathematik ist eine Zahl genau dann transzendent, wenn sie zwar reell, aber nicht algebraisch ist.
Wenn eine Variable existiert, die man mit dem griechischen Buchstaben *Chi* bezeichnet, könnte man also durchaus von einem *transzendenten Chi* sprechen. Allerdings gibt es dann kaum einen Zusammenhang mit *Licht*.
Der andere Begriff (*transzendental*) existiert in der Mathematik nicht.

**Beleuchtungstechnik**
In der Beleuchtungstechnik sind beide Begriffe nicht gebräuchlich. Transzendente oder transzendentale Lichter wird man auch kaum bei einem seriösen Raumausstatter kaufen können.

**Esoterik**
Daher vermute ich, dass wir es hier mit einem Fachbegriff aus der Esoterik zu tun haben, und dann wird es mit der Definition schwierig, weil ich die Erfahrung gemacht habe, dass Esoteriker gerne irgendwelche Begriffe entweder frei erfinden ohne dafür eine exakte Definition bereitzustellen, oder aus anderen Fachbereichen entlehnen, wobei deren dort gebräuchliche Definition meist sehr schwammig wird, wenn man sie auf Dinge anwendet, die nicht dem ursprünglichen Kontext angehören.

Im vorliegenden Fall ist ja schon unklar, was genau mit »*Licht*« gemeint sein soll. Wäre es tatsächlich eine elektromagnetische Welle mit einer Wellenlänge im optischen Bereich, oder ein Gegenstand, der solche Strahlung emittieren könnte, wären wir bei der Beleuchtungstechnik, wo es schlichtweg keinen Sinn ergibt, die fraglichen Adjektive zu verwenden.

Also versuche ich mal die Bedeutung der Adjektive selbst zu analysieren:

**transzendent**

Zusammengesetzt aus:

- *trans*: Lateinisch für »hinüber«, »auf der anderen Seite«, »jenseits«. Zu finden unter anderem auch in

  - *trans*portieren = hinübertragen
  - *trans*sexuell = sich dem anderen Geschlecht zugehörig fühlend
  - *Trans*sibirische Eisenbahn = eine Bahnverbindung, die einen auf die andere Seite von Sibirien bringt
- *cedo, cessi, cessum*: Lateinisch für »gehen«, »schreiten«

Das lateinische Ursprungswort *transcedo* bedeutet also »hinübergehen«, »überqueren« (z.B. einen Fluss), »überschreiten« (z.B. eine Türschwelle), »passieren« (z.B. einen Durchgang), »übertreten« (eine Grenz-Linie)

Ein *transzendentes Licht* ist also ein Licht, das irgend etwas überquert.

In der Philosophie hat sich für *transzendent* aber auch die folgende Bedeutung etabliert:

> Als *transzendent* gilt, was außerhalb oder jenseits eines Bereiches möglicher Erfahrung, insbesondere des Bereiches der normalen Sinneswahrnehmung liegt und nicht von ihm abhängig ist.

aus: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transzendenz

Somit könnte ein transzendentes Licht auch ein Licht sein, das man nicht wahrnehmen kann.

**transzendental**

Das ist nun ein Terminus, der in der Erkenntnistheorie entstanden ist, und von *transzendent* abgeleitet wurde. Dabei handelt es sich um ein Adjektiv, dass eine Eigenschaft von Fragestellungen, Erklärungsweisen und Erkenntnissen beschreibt. Folgende Definition stammt von Immanuel Kant:

> Ich nenne alle Erkenntnis *transzendental*, die sich nicht [...] mit Gegenständen, sondern mit unserer Erkenntnisart von Gegenständen, [...] beschäftigt.

Wie gesagt: Das gilt in der Erkenntnistheorie, einem Teilgebiet der Philosophie. Da man sich dort aber selten über Lichter unterhält, stellt sich dort gar nicht die Frage, was ein *transzendentales Licht* womöglich sein könnten.

In der Esoterik könnte man darunter verstehen, dass das Chi eine Erleuchtung (also »ein Licht, das einem aufgeht«, folglich eine Erkenntnis) ist, die sich mit der Art und Weise befasst, wie wir irgend etwas anderes wahrnehmen.

Answer (score 9):

**Transzendent** ist ein verhältnismäßig normales Wort und bedeutet laut Duden:

> **In der Philosophie**: die Grenzen der Erfahrung und der sinnlich erkennbaren Welt überschreitend; übersinnlich, übernatürlich
>
> **In der Mathematik**
>   über das Algebraische hinausgehend
>   Beispiel
>   transzendente Funktionen, Gleichungen

**Transzendental** ist eine Wortschöpfung Kants und Wikipedia zitiert diesen mit den Worten:

> „Ich nenne alle Erkenntnis transzendental, die sich nicht sowohl mit Gegenständen, sondern mit unserer Erkenntnisart von Gegenständen, so fern diese a priori möglich sein soll, überhaupt beschäftigt.“ (Immanuel Kant: AA III, 43[2]).

Insofern finde ich diese Formulierung falsch:

> Chi, das transzendentale Licht.

Diese jedoch bezüglich der Bedeutung etwas unklar:

> Chi, das transzendente Licht.

Es sei denn, man ginge wie Herr Schölnast zur lateinischen Bedeutung zurück.

Comment: Vielleicht geht es ja um das Licht der Erkenntnis. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Beides sind lateinische Worte. Die Endung *-ens* (im Deutschen *-ent*) markiert das Partizip Präsens Aktiv, die Endung *-alis* (im Deutschen *-al*) bezeichnet das zugehörige Adjektiv.

*Transzendent* ist also etwas, das Grenzen überschreitet; *transzendental* etwas, das eine solche Qualität aufweist.

Dementsprechend:

> Chi, das [transzendente](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transzendent) Licht 
>   Eine [transzendentale](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transzendental) Frage in der Philosophie.